# Date Time Object Conversion

Tags: c#

I have the following C# that is giving me the error above when trying to parse string to datetime.

```
DateTime currDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date.Trim(), "M/d/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currDate);
if (currDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    currDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Trim());
```

image flow label.text looks like this `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

Any ideas on how to convert this?

Comment: What is value of `date.Trim()`? Is there any relation with `label.text`?

Comment: Value of date.Trim() is 31 March 2015

Comment: No relation with label.text

Comment: Image flow label.text, i mean value of currDate

Answer (score 0):

You should have the format `d MMM yyyy` for `31 March 2015`

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(date.Trim(), 
                       "d MMM yyyy", 
                       none, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out currDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MMMM` format for specifying full month as specified in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN documentation.

and your code would look like this.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime currDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime.TryParseExact("31 March 2015", "dd MMMM yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currDate);
        Console.WriteLine(currDate);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/45PElV) is working dot net fiddle.

Comment: I tried all of the solutions but am getting the same error "The string was not recognized as a valid Date Time. There is an unknown word starting at index 1."

Comment: Let me make clear to all, in my code DateTime currDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                            DateTime.TryParseExact(date.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currDate);
                            if (currDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                                currDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Trim());

Comment: date has the value "31 March 2015" and the value of currDate is "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Thanks all in advance

Comment: I cannot specify "31 March 2015" , "d MMMM YYYY" because everytime the document cannot contain the same date

Comment: @Madhu Then use `Convert.ToDateTime` function.

Comment: "currDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Trim()); " Yaeh i used the same

Comment: "DateTime.TryParseExact("31 March 2015", "dd MMMM yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out currDate);
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("31 Mar 2015")); " In your you are specifying "31 March 2015" but everytime same date cannot occur, so I need to use date.Trim()" will it work with this?

Comment: @Madhu Of course adding Trim would make no difference there. You may try putting different possible input to Convert.ToDateTime function.

Comment: @Madhu -- if your question is, if you could use your `date.Trim()` in place of `"31 March 2015"`, then the answer is yes. `"31 March 2015"` is just an example. What you *do* have to make sure is that `date.Trim()` will actually always *be* in the format `"d MMMM yyyy"`.